# Form filling slot after user replying to out of scope message

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I have the following story:

```
story: survey continue                                                      
  steps:                                                                   
  - intent: greet                                                          
  - action: utter_greet                                                    
  - intent: affirm                                                         
  - action: health_form                                                    
  - active_loop: health_form                                               
  - intent: out_of_scope                                                   
  - action: utter_ask_continue                                             
  - intent: affirm                                                         
  - action: health_form                                                    
  - active_loop: null                                                      
  - action: utter_slots_values
```

And let's assume the following conversation:

```
1 Me: hello
2 Bot: Hi! It's time for your daily wellness check. Tracking healthy habits is a great way to measure your progress over time. Would you like to answer a few questions about your health?
3 Me: yes please
4 Bot: Did you exercise yesterday? Don't sweat it if you didn't run a marathon - walks count!
5 Me: wait stop
6 Bot: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Do you want to continue?
7 Me: actually yes
8 Bot: What kind of exercise did you do?
```

As you can see, in the 7th message if the user makes an affirmation intent it answers the question proposed in the 6th message as well as the one proposed in the 4th message.

I would expect a conversation flow like this:

```
[...]
6 Bot: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Do you want to continue?
7 Me: actually yes
8 Bot: Did you exercise yesterday? Don't sweat it if you didn't run a marathon - walks count!
```

Is this expected behavior? How can I achieve the expected flow that I have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your form to run again under `active_loop`, instead of null. A sample story from the Rasa official website on how to "return" to the form after another intent [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/forms)

```
rules:
- rule: Example of an unhappy path
  condition:
  # Condition that form is active.
  - active_loop: restaurant_form
  steps:
  # This unhappy path handles the case of an intent `chitchat`.
  - intent: chitchat
  - action: utter_chitchat
  # Return to form after handling the `chitchat` intent
  - action: restaurant_form
  - active_loop: restaurant_form
```